# Is it possible to save SMS in folders?

Tags: sms

Can I create folders and move sms's that I want to keep to these folders? For example, I would want to save all my sent sms's in a Sent folder.

Comment: If this is just to back them up then try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore

Comment: Not really for backup. Rather to organise and easily recover important messages. E.g. if I am sent settings for the phone, it would be nice to save it in a folder called "References". Also, all my sent messages could be saved in a "Sent" folder.

Comment: Any updates from your end? Does the SMS Folders work for you?

Comment: this app can create folders https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169892