# How to block incoming advertisement sms from senders with no visible phone number?

Tags: sms, sms-blocking

I get spam ad messages from a few companies regularly on my phone. And when I try to block them using the option given on the messaging application a custom message says that the number is invalid and cannot be blocked. So, how to stop such messages sent by unknown numbers?

Comment: This may work for you- it does for me. 1. create a contact for this purpose with spurious number 2.Use Textra messaging app and from *People in Conversation>add contact* add to the contact created in 1 3. Blacklist it

Comment: "create a contact for this purpose with spurious number". The problem is that the sender has no visible number! @beeshyams

Comment: Just give it any number- like 999999, which isn't valid. Then you add this sms contact as pager/ home or any other option

Comment: @beeshyams Textra doesn't work (isn't compatible) on my Samsung tab 4. Any other option?

Comment: Sorry, but I do remember that this question was asked before and answered- suggest you search this site thoroughly

Comment: Does turning off ( Wap Push Message's ) in the default messaging app work  ?

Comment: @NoobFood What does that do? And how to turn off Wap Push Message? I have a Samsung device (Tab 4).

Comment: Wap Push messages allow websites to send messages through the internet or PUSH them through, I think Facebook has a push notifications feature like this ! ... You can turn it off by going into the default messaging applications settings and unselecting Allow Wap Push messages

Answer (score 1):

Try this [SMS Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=main.organizer.sms.trailblaze.smsorganizer&hl=en) app.

Apart from a host of other features, this app lets you set 'rules'. For example, you can set a rule to auto delete any message when the sender's phone number/contact name contains a certain sequence.

[image]

If you are unsure about deleting, you can also set the rule to move the sms to a folder (This app also lets you create folders for sms), say a spam folder